# $S_1, \dots, S_6 \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,21\},$ prove either $|S_i \cap S_j| \ge 5$ or $|S_i^C \cap S_j^C| \ge 5$ for some $i,j.$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, pigeonhole-principle, probabilistic-method

Given subsets $S_1, \dots, S_6 \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,21\},$ I wish to prove either $|S_i \cap S_j| \ge 5$ or $|S_i^C \cap S_j^C| \ge 5$ for some $i \ne j.$

I started off by assuming $|S_i^C \cap S_j^C| \le 4$ for all $i \ne j.$ This gives us $|S_i \cup S_j| \ge 17$ for all $i \ne j,$ and we wish to find an intersection of size $\ge 5.$ I tried the probabilistic method, pigeonhole principle, and proof by contradiction, but none of these techniques worked.

So far I've gotten that if the result does not hold, we have $8 \le |S_i| \le 14$ for all $i,$ but I cannot rule out these cases. I also tried to draw segments within a $6 \times 21$ rectangle to find sets which violated the condition, and always failed by the time I got to the $5$th row, so maybe the bound isn't even that sharp. The problem with the probabilistic method is that $p(k \in S_i \, \& \, k \in S_j) \ne p(k \in S_i)p(k \in S_j)$ since the events are not independent. If you use conditional probabilities to fix this, you end up getting $\mathbb{E}(|S_i \cup S_j|) = \dots = \mathbb{E}(|S_i \cup S_j|).$ This problem is outside the realm of horseshoe combinatorics, so such an equality is not helpful. The issue with the pigeonhole principle is that while it will give you interesting bounds on numbers within $\{1,2,\dots,21\}$ appearing in at least this or that amount of sets $S_i,$ it will not produce a set of numbers appearing in two sets simultaneously; you might be drawing different numbers over and over.

Does anyone have a hint or idea about how to proceed? What would be the motivation behind a successful approach?

Comment: Where does this problem come from, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I made it myself.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that this is true?

Comment: @DodoDuQuercy I showed that it's equivalent to a problem that is true, so yes.

Comment: But then you already have a proof, so why ask the question here?

Comment: @Display name: Just for my understanding - when you say "Given subsets $S_1, \dots, S_6 \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,21\},$ I wish to prove either $|S_i \cap S_j| \ge 5$ or $|S_i^C \cap S_j^C| \ge 5$ for **some** $i \ne j.$", does this mean that you just have to find concerete $i$ and $j$ for which your claim is true (in which case you just find these indexes) or does this claim have to hold for **all** $i$ and $j$ with $i \not= j$ (in which case I think that you could alter the problem description)? Am I mistaken? If so, then sorry.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Unfortunately, I only know that problem is true because I have to prove it. I reduced to an equivalent problem which I am asking here.

Comment: @Tortoise We need to find just one example of $i,j.$

Comment: So when I asked you where the problem came from, and you answered, "I made it myself", you were being considerably less informative than one might have hoped. Time to come clean, Display name: what was the original problem, and why do you have to prove it?

Comment: Please, Display name, engage with my comment.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The original problem was the coloring version I just gave in my answer, and I wanted to prove it in order to practice combinatorics. It turns out that translating the problem did not make it any easier.

Comment: @GerryMyerson By the way, I think I've seen you post before, but your profile is sparse. Did you delete some of your questions and answers?

Comment: Somehow I became disconnected from my previous account, and haven't gotten around to getting reconnected yet. I'm glad you found a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Take the incidence matrix setup where rows correspond to $S_i$ and columns correspond to elements $j$. Place a 1 if $j \in S_i$, 0 otherwise.

We count column pairs of both types $1-1$ and $0-0$.
In each column, if there are $k$ ones, then there are $ { k \choose 2 } + { 6-k \choose 2 } \geq 6 $ column pairs.
So there are at least $ 21 \times 6 = 126 $ column pairs.

There are $ { 6 \choose 2 } = 15 $ pairs of rows, which contain these 126 column pairs.
By the PP, at least 1 pair of rows contains at least $ \lceil \frac{126}{15} \rceil = 9 $ pairs.
By the PP, at least $\lceil \frac{9}{2} \rceil = 5$ pairs are of the same type (either $1-1$ or $0-0$).
Translating back, this pair of subsets contain at least 5 elements in common ($1-1$), or not at all ($0-0$).

Answer (score 1):

I have found a proof. Choices of $S_1, \dots, S_6$ correspond to coloring the squares of a $6 \times 21$ rectangle white or black according to whether the elements lie in $S_i$ or not. We want to find $2$ rows and $5$ columns such that the $10$ squares at the intersections of these rows and columns are all the same color. If a column has $k$ black squares and $6-k$ white pairs, it contains $\binom{6-k}{2} + \binom{k}{2} \ge 6$ monochromatic pairs. There are $2$ colors and $\binom{6}{2} = 15$ positions for a pair, so there are $30$ position-color combinations for a column pair. Since $6 \cdot 21 > 30 \cdot 4,$ some color and position combination appears at least $5$ times as desired.

Comment: I do not understand your proof. If I follow you correctly, you're counting column pairs, meanin an element's membership in both subsets is the same. I'm not sure what "$2 \times 15 = 30$ possible pairs for any column" means. There are $2^6$ possible color combinations, corresponding to whether the element $i$ is in each of the subsets.

Comment: Also, note that your column pairs include 1-1 and 0-0. Merely showing that a pair of rows has 5 column pairs is not sufficient, since 3 of them could be 1-1 and 2 of them could be 0-0. See my solution.

Comment: @CalvinLin The $30$ pairs correspond to the $2 \cdot \binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose a color for the column pair and then choose a position for the column pair. Some position and color combination shows up at least 5 times.

Comment: I'm sorry, restating exactly what you wrote doesn't make it any clearer for me. What is a possible position-color combination for a column pair? Could you give an example? E.g. I think you're referring to the column vector 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, of which there are $2^6$ possible combinations.

Comment: @CalvinLin The possible colors are black and white and the possible positions are any $2$ positions within the column. In the column $BWBBWW,$ the column pairs would be B\_B\_ \_ \_, B\_ \_B\_ \_, \_ \_BB\_ \_, \_W\_ \_W\_, \_W\_ \_ \_W, \_ \_ \_ \_WW. In general, the possible pairs are BB\_ \_ \_ \_, B\_B\_ \_ \_, ..., B\_ \_ \_ \_B,...,\_ \_ \_ \_BB, and then the same with white instead of black.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now. Thanks for explaining. Your solution is essentially identical to mine.